# Show that there is no surjective smooth function $S^1 \to S^1\times S^1\times S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

This is not homework, but a sample test question.  The question is:

> Show that there is no surjective smooth function $$S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1.$$

Now I can see that, for example $$S^1 \to S^1$$ is infinitely differentiable with the identity map from the 1-D circle in 2-D space to itself.

Now I am wondering, due to the nature of the test material, if somehow I am supposed to either apply Gaussian curvature or the Gauss-Bonett formula.  I am also familiar a little bit with the fundamental forms.

While it looks like there should not be a surjective function (not even considering smooth), as all the points on $S^1$ could themselves just be mapped to the $S^1$ of the $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$.  What is this surface called (I am not even sure what it looks like).

Thanks,
Brian.

Comment: This isn't really related to your question and I'm not really good at set theory, but it seems that there probably is a "surjective function" if you forget all adjectives because $S^1$ and $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ is a three-dimensional torus, not a surface.

Comment: Matt, yeah, I am still a bit hazy on how things like this could not be surjective - even if just looking at a segment of S^1 or some interval on the real numbers.  But then of course this mapping would be injective also and hence a bijection.  But from this:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54232/difference-between-bijection-and-isomorphism It seems but being a bijection alone doesn't make it an isomorphism.  I "feel" that this shouldn't be an isomorphism but don't know how to show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know a bit about Sard's theorem, it is straightforward.
Assume that there exists a smooth map $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1\times S^1\times S^1=\mathbb T^3$.

On one side, Sard's theorem tells you that it must exist a regular value of $f$: that is a point $y\in \mathbb T^3$ such that $\forall x\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$, the derivative $d_xf:T_xS^1\rightarrow T_{f(x)}\mathbb T^3$ is surjective.

On the other side, if $f$ is surjective then for any $y\in \mathbb T^3$, the set $f^{-1}(y)$ is not empty and for every $x\in f^{-1}(y)$, the rank of $d_xf$ is at most $1$ : a contradiction.

About geometric arguments, most of the stuff you want to use are about surfaces but the question seems to be far from two dimensional things (by the way which surface are you talking about at the end?).

Comment: and then how are we getting contradiction?

Comment: $d_xf$ is a linear map whose rank is 1, then what is the contradiction? I am missing something

Comment: Rank of $d_xf$ is at most one, so cannot be surjective ($T_{f(x)} \mathbb T^3$ is $3$-dimensional) @permutation_matrix

Comment: Wait, What is the use for the fact that $f$ is surjective? Is it to ensure that a 
 critical value $y \in \mathbb{T}^3$ exists using sard's theorem?

Comment: @permutation_matrix Sard's theorem says that there is a regular value: $y\in \mathbb T^3$. But by definition of a regular value, every $y$ not in the image of $f$ is a regular value and in this case no contradiction is arrived.